# Ruby refuses to acknowledge that I've installed Rubygems... Why?

Tags: ruby

```
C:\Users\wipe\Quora-Personal-Analytics>ruby hello.rb
hello
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original
_require': no such file to load -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in
`require'
        from hello.rb:4

C:\Users\wipe\Quora-Personal-Analytics>ruby require 'date'
ruby: No such file or directory -- require (LoadError)

C:\Users\wipe\Quora-Personal-Analytics>ruby require 'rubygems'
ruby: No such file or directory -- require (LoadError)

C:\Users\wipe\Quora-Personal-Analytics>
```

===

I'm using Ruby 1.8.7. Also, this worked before (on the same computer).

The require statements all *do* work when I try things from interactive ruby.So they all are installed. But I need the command line.

==

Edit: Here are the contents of Hello.rb

```
puts "hello"

require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'

require 'date'
require 'watir'
require 'optparse'
```

And some new error:

```
C:\Users\wipe\Quora-Personal-Analytics>ruby require 'rubygems'
ruby: No such file or directory -- require (LoadError)

C:\Users\wipe\Quora-Personal-Analytics>ruby hello.rb
hello
←[31mCould not find OptionParser-0.5.1 in any of the sources←[0m
←[33mRun `bundle install` to install missing gems.←[0m

C:\Users\wipe\Quora-Personal-Analytics>ruby bundle install
ruby: No such file or directory -- bundle (LoadError)

C:\Users\wipe\Quora-Personal-Analytics>ruby -e "require 'date'"

C:\Users\wipe\Quora-Personal-Analytics>ruby -e "require 'rubygems'"

C:\Users\wipe\Quora-Personal-Analytics>ruby QuoraStats.rb "firstname-lastname"
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original
_require': no such file to load -- httparty (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in
`require'
        from ./lib/Content.rb:1
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in
`gem_original_require'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in
`require'
        from QuoraStats.rb:10
```

Somehow, ruby bundle install doesn't work very well:

```
C:\Users\wipe\Quora-Personal-Analytics>ruby bundle install
ruby: No such file or directory -- bundle (LoadError)
```

Comment: what happens if you simply type `ruby`? Error or not?

Comment: It doesn't output anything - it just stays there forever and I have to Ctrl-C the process

Comment: C:\Users\wipe\Quora-Personal-Analytics>ruby

^like that

Comment: ok, no I thought it was something I got lately... But I overlooked sth. in the stacktrace. One moment...

Comment: Well, for one, you are trying to get something related to Quora running by asking StackOverflow.

Comment: you are sure that bundler is installed?

Comment: I'm just trying to run http://www.quora.com/Stormy-Shippy/Quora-Community/Quora-Personal-Analytics-Part-1-Answers . But regardless, this error happens with anything Ruby-related

Comment: Hm - what bundler? Even with non-Quora applications, it still happens. E.g. I can't even require 'rubygems' for some reason...

Comment: But this is fine:


"irb(main):001:0> require 'rubygems'


=> true
irb(main):002:0> require 'firewatir'
=> true"

Comment: Your ruby program needs to be either in a text file which you pass on the command line `ruby program.rb`, or in a string after the -e flag `ruby -e 'require "rubygems"'` or on the command line if you pass it no flags (this is why it hangs, its waiting for you to enter the program).
-----
From here it looks like you don't have bundler: `$ gem install bundler` After that, you'll need to make sure you have all the gems: `$ bundle install` and then you can run again under bundler: `$ bundle exec ruby hello.rb` and it should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you don't have bundler installed. Try running `gem install bundler`, and then rerun `ruby hello.rb`.

Also, the two last commands you're typing won't work. `ruby require 'date'` is going to try to run the file "require" and pass it the argument `'date'`, not execute `require 'date'`. To just execute one line of ruby, use the `-e` flag, like this:

```
ruby -e "require 'date'"
```

Comment: But then when I try to run hello.rb, it outputs this for some reason:

←[31mCould not find OptionParser-0.5.1 in any of the sources←[0m
←[33mRun `bundle install` to install missing gems.←[0m

Comment: Did you try to run `bundle install`?

Comment: Yeah I tried. But it outputted this error. =/

'C:\Users\wipe\Quora-Personal-Analytics>ruby bundle install
ruby: No such file or directory -- bundle (LoadError)

C:\Users\wipe\Quora-Personal-Analytics>ruby install bundle
ruby: No such file or directory -- install (LoadError)'

Comment: OH now I tried and it's installing. Let's see how it goes from there

Comment: Wow thanks very much - that finally worked! Just out of curiosity - what is the ruby bundler? And is it usually automatically installed?

Comment: @InquilineKea [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/) is program that allows you to manage dependencies. Since you will require certain versions of gems, and they may require certain versions of each other, it can solve which versions you need to install. It is not included with Ruby, you need to actually run `gem install bundler` to install it.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't prefix every command with `ruby`. The only time you actually need to say `ruby ...` is when you are running a file. When you are running `bundle install`, then your shell will find the "bundle" file, see that it says it should be run with ruby due to a special comment on the top, called the hashbang, and your shell will then run `ruby /path/to/the/actual/bundle install`, where `/path/to/the/actual` is the path to the bundle file. To see this path you can run `which bundle`.

Answer (score 1):

Your stacktrace says

> `gem_original
>   _require': no such file to load -- bundler/setup (LoadError)

Did you make sure bundler is actually installed? If not, try

```
gem install bundler
```

and retry.

Edit:

With the new errors you receive, simply try running

```
`bundle install`
```

then try again.

Comment: Ah thanks very much! Yeah I just installed it. Though now it's outputting a new error (shown in the edited title post). :(